# How to align nav bar to left and make content display on right side... without using any frameworks like bootstrap or tailwind

Tags: html, css

I should complete this challenge without using any frameworks and only HTML and CSS. I am struck by how I can align nav items on the left of the screen and content to the right side and later images at the bottom of the content and images div should not take over the nav container.

This is how output should look on desktop

[image]

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot to unpack, so I'll answer in the order you asked:

Firstly, you mostly need to polish your CSS to make that layout, since it's mostly either a column or row, flexbox should help. You can check freecodecamp's responsive design certification and take the flexbox bit (box model too to understand how spacing works). Plus, they cover a similar card as the lunch examples in the CSS section

With those prerequisites, I believe this should make more sense:

NOTE: When I refer to specific parts of the page, I'm assuming you have everything inside a single parent element

e.g.

```
<nav> {title, list of links, card button}</nav>
```

a. To split the two groups , you can wrap the side `nav` and whatever contains the content, I'll assume it's a `div` in a single parent,(also div) :

```
<div class="parent"><!--Parent-->

<nav><!--Side-bar--></nav> 
<div class="content"><!--Content--></div> 

</div>
```

then set that as a flex container with `display: flex`  to lay the items out as rows (Default) and there you have it. You could also `justify-content: space-around` to give space between the menu and content, or use `margin-right` on the menu alone.

b. To ensure the div containing those images doesn't spill over into the `nav` , you can set the `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: scroll` property on it to hide the overflowing elements or enable scrolling through when elements overflow.

Extra:

You can layout the images in a row by placing them in a parent such as a `div` with `display: flex` , then add space between them by setting the margin-right property on each image using a class, or by using `justify-content: space-between`

Example code with the above markup:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

nav {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
}

.content {
  background-color: green;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.cards{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 30%;
  overflow: scroll hidden;
 }
.overflow{
  width: 150%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
 }
```

```html
<!--Parent-->
<div class="parent">

  <!--Side-bar-->
  <nav>Navigation</nav>
  
   <!--Content-->
  <div class="content">
    Content

    <!--Title text-->
    <h1>Title text</h1>

    <!--Card wrapper with overflow-->
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="overflow">Image overflow</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

This will give the general layout required for the menu and content

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please read [answer]. Questions that do not meet the SO guidelines shouldn't be answered (such as this one). You made a lot of efford though to answer it and I going to recognize this and as such not down-vote you on this one. However, for further answers please use a [repro] to validate your answer.

Comment: Hi @tacoshy thanks for the heads up! I'll read through the guidelines,  should I take the answer down?

Comment: no you should not. You have put quite a lot of efford already into it. IMHO it would be the best approach to add a [repro] to validate your answer (proof that your answer would solve the issue). As such it would meet the guidelines for a good answer.

Comment: How to place those card items below the text container. here is my code can you please work it out bro, https://github.com/vineeth767676/Landing-Home-Page

Comment: That has been addressed in the most recent edit